# Why do vector lines disappear when I zoom in?

Tags: qgis

I have a vector layer of polygons with number labels, it looks like this:

[image]

However, when I zoom in, some of the lines disappear:

[image]

I've disabled all parameters in the layer's `Rendering` section so I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. I'm using `QGIS-3.36.0`.

Comment: One of the first things to do with oddball rendering is to check and if necessary fix the geometry of the layer.

Comment: @John do you have any suggestions for doing that? Is there a tool for identifying issues?

Comment: And if it's a problem with the layer, why would the zoom level affect it? That sounds to me like something else is going on here since the layer shouldn't know/care about the zoom level.

Comment: The easiest way to do it is to run the check geometries tool.  There is a fix geometries tool that can usually fix those.  Bad geometry can affect rendering.